# Como fazer um form com campo data? (DD/MM/YYYY)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, formulário, kohana

Sou iniciante em Kohana e preciso fazer um form com um campo data. Meu formulário é esse:

```
<?=form::open('controllerInscricao/index')?>
<?php echo form::select('TURMA_codturma', $TURMA_codturma); ?> <br><br>

<div>Matricula: <?=form::input('ALUNO_MATRICULA' );?></div>
<div>Data: </div>
<?php echo '<div'.HTML::attributes($attrs).'>'.$content.'</div>'; ?>
<?=form::submit('btn_submit', 'Salvar') ?>
<?=form::close()?>
```

Como fazer um campo txt no formato DD/MM/YYYY ?

Comment: Ficou vago. Você quer um campo text com o formato `DD/MM/YYYY`, um campo para cada dia mes ano, ou um select?

Comment: Um campo text com formato DD/MM/YYYY, esqueci de especificar.

Comment: Nesse caso é um input comum, mas o filtro para `DD/MM/YYYY` deverá ser feito pelo JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recomendo a utilização do datepicker + maskedinput.
Eu utilizo a versão 1.3.1 do maskedinput que funciona em IE mais antigos.

Links da documentação e downloads:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

O código ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
<input type="text" id="data />

$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pt']);

$("#data").mask("99/99/9999");

$('#data').datepicker();
```

OBS:
Esses dois plugins já lhe poupará tempo na questão de verificar se foram inclusos no plugin apenas números.

Comment: Dei UP pela resposta em si, entretanto, dizer *que não precisará fazer verificação nenhuma, pois esses dois plugins já tomam conta*, é um tremendo equívoco. Não existe validação no lado do cliente, JS não passa de máscara. Alias, o nome do plugin é **MASK**.

Comment: Concordo Papa Charlie, acho que me expressei mal, me referia a validações simples, como  verificar se foram inclusos apenas números.

Comment: Nesse caso cai como uma luva e realmente mata as verificações pelo lado do cliente. Já que editou a questão, irei remover o comentário acima e esse também. OK?

Comment: Aí fica ao seu critério, eu deixaria, pois pode solucionar alguma dúvida de outra pessoa.

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro a utilização do plugin `datepicker` do `jqueryui`: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Exemplo de código:

```
// Cria-se um input padrão com um id para identificar ele
<diva>Data: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></div>
```

E adicione o script ao fim da página:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // #datepicker é o seletor para o campo criado
  // datepicker() é o método do plugin que diz que aquele campo
  // deverá obedecer as regras de data
  $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
```